# How does not voting support republicans?

Tags: election, voting

I keep seeing things like this image:
[image: Two pictures with captions]

Which says if my candidate doesn't get the nomination, then I won't vote at all. And then it shows Trump saying thank you.

How does not voting at all actually help 1 party?

Comment: Can you explain what is unclear?  Fewer people voting for the Democratic candidate makes said candidate less likely to win, and thus the Republican candidate more likely to win.  It does not refer to voters who were considering voting for Trump as well as the others.

Comment: http://www.learnnc.org/lp/multimedia/13293

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The message behind the image is that if **Democrats** don't vote, then that helps the Republicans.

Both of the people depicted in that image support a Democrat, so it's reasonable to assume that they are Democratic voters.  If they were depicted as being supporters of Republican candidates, then the conclusion would have been different.

Answer (score 3):

Some people are idealistic and only want to vote for a candidate that they actually want to see in power. That's what the top image is describing.

However, this isn't really how politics works most of the time. I doubt there are many who would say that they agree with everything any candidate says and is. What it's not explaining is that those that support only one of the Democratic candidates might disagree with the other, but they disagree with the Republican candidates even more. As Bill Maher says (I'm paraphasing, I can't remember his exact statement), on choosing an in-flight meal on a plane, if you prefer the fish over the chicken, you go for the fish, but if you can't have it you don't just say, "I'll go hungry then."

So considering it an all-or-nothing proposition badly misunderstands how politics works. You should go for whichever candidate is the best, regardless of whether you agree with everything they say.

Answer (score 2):

Assume that the election is tied.  If you vote, you can determine the outcome.  If you don't vote, the Republicans win on a tiebreaker.  It feels a bit unreal, but it is possible.  For example, the Republicans probably would win the tiebreaker if no one wins a majority of the electoral votes.  They are expected to control more than half the state delegations in the House.  So if you do not vote for Hillary, the effect is that the Republican candidate wins.

A more realistic scenario is that millions of other people are facing the exact same choice.  It's unlikely that one person could swing the election, but in [2004](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_States_presidential_election,_2004), Republicans won Ohio by 118,601 votes.  So if 120,000 more people had voted Democrat, Ohio would have switched, giving Kerry 271 electoral college votes and the win.

Of course, it's also quite possible that there are millions of people who would slightly prefer the Republican candidate.  Their not voting helps the Democrat instead.

And this is coming out in the primary season.  Votes now have no direct effect in the general election.  What they may be saying is that Bernie would be less effective than Hillary in the general election.  So not voting for Hillary in the primary could have the effect of allowing other, more motivated voters to give the Democratic nomination to Bernie.  Perhaps Bernie is less able to compete with Trump and loses.  Or everyone votes for Hillary, the emails thing gets her convicted, and the Republican candidate wins by default.  That's the problem with speculation:  it may not go the way that you think.